# HDMI not detected using 7" touchscreen display on Gigabyte Brix running Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, hdmi, touchscreen

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Gigabyte Brix with Intel HD Graphics.  I'm trying to connect a 7" touchscreen display from Adafruit.  The touchscreen part is responsive and working correctly but there is nothing showing on the display.  xrandr outputs that the HDMI port is disconnected.  If I plug another monitor into the computer I can get a display.  Switching back to the touchscreen display will fix the problem but I need the display to work on startup.  Is there a way to force the HDMI output even though it thinks the HDMI port is disconnected?